# Select data with a time range on any date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query orders between certain time frames. I understand how you can do it on a certain date, but I would like to select all orders from 3:00PM-7:00PM, or 12:00AM-10:00AM, and so on. Is this possible? Also, if you wouldn't mind, I would like some sort of explanation because I am new to SQL. 
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? Show us your query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify what you want in your where clause like the following examples:

```
Where OrderFrom between '3:00PM' and '7:00PM'
```

Or you can do like that :

```
Where OrderFrom >= '3:00PM' and OrderFrom <= '7:00PM'
```

Comment: It's that simple? I was reading a lot of stuff on having to convert the data into DateTime or something

Comment: This only works if `OrderDate` is type `TIME` and you don't care about the date.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an OrderDate column that is a `DATETIME` type, you can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM <YourTableName>
WHERE CAST(OrderDate AS DATE) = <YourDateValue>
    AND (
            CAST(OrderDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '3:00PM' AND '7:00PM'
            OR CAST(OrderDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '12:00AM' AND '10:00AM'
        )
```

If you leave out the `DATE` comparison, all `DATETIME` values that have a `TIME` component between your hours will be returned, regardless of date.

Take a look at this example:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (val DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #test (val)
VALUES ('2018-01-04 09:00:00.000')
,('2018-01-04 10:00:00.000')
,('2018-01-04 11:00:00.000')
,('2018-01-04 12:00:00.000')
,('2018-01-05 09:00:00.000')
,('2018-01-05 10:00:00.000')
,('2018-01-05 11:00:00.000')
,('2018-01-05 12:00:00.000')

SELECT * FROM #test
WHERE CAST(val AS TIME) BETWEEN '9:00AM' AND '11:00AM'
```

The results of this query are:

```
val
2018-01-04 09:00:00.000
2018-01-04 10:00:00.000
2018-01-04 11:00:00.000
2018-01-05 09:00:00.000
2018-01-05 10:00:00.000
2018-01-05 11:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

```
select * from date_table where date ='date1' and time between 'time1' and 'time2'
```

give your values for date1, time1 and time2

You can use above query to get the output for any day in between particular time.